# Terraform multiple environments on aws

Tags: terraform

So currently i have one VPC and one ec2 instance. I want to have 2 environments (prod and qa) that share the same vpc.
I created a module named vpc but i am not sure how to have the vpc shared beetween workspaces.

If i change the workspace and run terraform plan it will recreated a brand new VPC. Is there such a think of shared module in workspaces? Or a global module?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already on track to using modules, I propose the use of remote state.

The short track would be to add a [remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) data source to import your existing environment into the new one. This will allow you to reference the existing VPC.

If you wish to move the VPC to its own Environment, you can remove it from the current Environments state and import it e.g. in a VPC Environment.